# Unity: Exporting Game creates Texture Glitches

Tags: unity, textures

In the editor the textures are fine, however upon exporting I'm constantly faced with glitches like these:

[image]

I mainly use the Built-in Standard Specular Shader and the texture that gets glitched is always the Detail Texture. When re-exporting the game multiple times the texture gets glitched exactly the same way in the same spots.

Meshes are always below 65536 polygons. In game size is usually around 2x2 kilometres. The smallest Terrainmesh is 500x300metres and the origins are usually close to the terrain, always at 0,0,0. Scale and Rotation are always reset.

This has happened in pretty much every scene so far.

[image]

Screenshot of UV coordinates:

[image]

Comment: Do you have mesh compression enabled on any of these meshes in their import settings? This could quantize the UV coordinates to below the precision of a tiling that repeats at 128 times the frequency of the base map.

Comment: @DmGregory Mesh compression is disabled. I've also tried messing with disabling optimize Mesh, Weld vertices and setting Tangents to import.

Comment: Okay, next guess: how big are these meshes, and how far are the parts where you see the artifacts from the mesh's origin / the world's origin? How far out are they in UV space?

Comment: Meshes are always below 65536 polygons. In game size is usually around 2x2 kilometres. The smallest Terrainmesh is 500x300metres however the origin is roughly 1km away.

Comment: @DMGregory When I re-build the game, the artifacts always spawn at the same place unless I change the UV's. So I made a little test and moved the origin of the Terrain Mesh from 0,0,0 to pretty much where some artifacts were. After re-building all artifacts remained at precisely the same spot, only a few metres away from the new origin.

Comment: Sounds like you should detail those diagnostic steps in your question. I'm not sure if I'm understanding you precisely, so showing relevant diagrams/screenshots may help. Don't forget to answer the question about uv space.

Comment: @DMGregory So for the past 2 hours I've been re-building the project dozens of times trying to isolate the problem by trial & error. Scaling the Terrain, Changing the texture tiling. I've duplicated the terrain 10x into the scene trying every possibility. I found no consistent factors that would isolate the problem. The most confusing thing, I disabled all the enemy bots in the actual project and that removed all artifacts on the terrain in the final build: https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/86cb24-1589988568.jpg So yeah, I really don't know where to look.

Comment: @DMGregory Don't know what you mean with uv space. Added a screenshot of the UV maps though.